# check for a streaming item in a huge list

Tags: performance, list, stream, lookup

This is the problem we are trying to solve. 
We are dealing with huge streaming data of a large number of items. We also have a predefined list of items. We need to check if each item in a stream belongs to my predefined list which is very huge (some 4 million items). The lookup/check up operation should be as efficient as possible

It would be great if people here could help me in giving pointers to papers/algorithms that I can read to approach this problem in the right manner.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to narrow down a few assumptions before coming to a solution

- Will your predefined list fit in main memory?
- What will the access pattern look like? Will most of the streamed items be of the same type or will all types be represented equally?
- Are your items small (integers/short strings)? If not, is there a unique identifier attached to each one?
- Is the pre-defined list static or will it change? How frequently?

Generally speaking you will want to maintain a hashtable of objects (or unique keys representing those objects) and look up each object as it comes in via your stream. Hash tables provide *fast* lookups, and if your data set is static they are ideal for the use case you describe. However there are some situations where other solutions may perform better, the above questions should reveal whether this is the case.

For further reading I will point you towards the [Data Structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) and [Big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation articles on Wikipedia

**Edit:** I hacked together this quick program to measure hash lookup performance in python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import random
import string
import time

# return a random username, all lowercase, between n and m characters long
def generate_username(min_length = 5, max_length = 10):
    n = random.randint(min_length, max_length)
    return ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, n))

# Build a hash table of 4mil usernames (the 'predefined items')
users = set()
for i in xrange(4000000):
    users.add(generate_username())

# Build a 'stream' of usernames to check against the hash table
stream = []
for i in xrange(10000000):
    stream.append(generate_username())

# Measure performance of hash lookups for 10mil usernames
start = time.clock()
for name in stream:
    if name in users:
        pass #print "%s is present" % name
end = time.clock()

print "%fs (%f - %f)" % (end - start, start, end)
```

Results:

```
3.660000s (238.100000 - 241.760000)
```

So in Python you can check 10million usernames in under 4 seconds, equivalent to streaming >17MB/s. How fast do you really need it? :)

Comment: To answer your questions 1) My List would not fit in main memory. 2) The access patterns would be of the same type. 3) My items are short strings. To be more specific. They are user-names. 4) Also the List is a static one. It will not change. Incremental updates of my list is not of concern to me. I was thinking along the lines of using a Hash Table as well. Since, my incoming data is a high speed stream, I was looking for pointers for highly efficient hashing algorithms that are used in a stream setting

Comment: Usernames probably average about 10 bytes at most. `4mil * 10 = 40MB`, am I missing something?

Comment: Some more questions for you: how fast is 'high-speed'? Gigabit speeds? Faster? What is the desired response time? What is the latency of the link?

Comment: For the intial prototype, we are concerned only about usernames ! but the conservative assumption is that a lot more lookups might need to be done later like email-ids, location, etc.

Comment: If you have plans for growth I have to question whether a database might be more appropriate. I expect you will have some concerns about efficiency, but I suggest you quantify the required performance levels before discounting a database (in-memory embedded databases can be [very fast](http://fallabs.com/kyotocabinet/))